# Cross-Browser Communication

Tags: javascript, html

I am designing a website that requires a host and client websites. The host will set something up (a session), and the clients will connect to that host using an ID specific to that session.

I have considered how I will facilitate that communication, and initially I was going to have both the clients and the host periodically query and update a database which holds the current states of all clients and the host to communicate new options and changes - but then I wondered if it is possible, using javascript [or something], for them to connect and communicate directly?

The communication would be very simple messages - single strings to communicate current state and stuff like that.

Im pretty proficient in javascript/html/css, but am happy to learn if there is something that would do a better job of setting this up.

Thanks!
Alex

Comment: P2P is pretty difficult, but something like Websockets would probably do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [httprelay.io](http://httprelay.io), requires no additional libraries and can be used for simple http client to client communication.

Comment: oh cool, that looks good. I have been using PeerJS which works but hasnt been updated in years. Do you know how frequently httprelay is updated?

Comment: Every day. Feedback or feature request would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [WebRTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC), which is the *de facto* and recommended way of doing peer-to-peer connections through the web with pure Javascript:

> WebRTC (Web Real-Time Communication) is an API definition drafted by the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) that supports **browser-to-browser applications** for voice calling, video chat, and P2P file sharing without the need of either internal or external plugins.

And yes, before you ask, simple messages can be exchanged as well.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/WebRTC/Peer-to-peer_communications_with_WebRTC) is the Mozilla reference explaining WebRTC.

[Here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/) is a nice simple tutorial to get you started with the code.

[Here](https://opentokrtc.com/) is a peer-to-peer chat room with video capabilities built using pure WebRTC as a demo.

---

Prior to WebRTC, there was no satisfactory decentralised way of doing this.

As the comments indicate, Websockets would have been the right idea if you were going with a centralised system - they facilitate real-time communication between clients and a central host.

Decentralised systems, however, must be implemented using WebRTC - this is the only option on the cards.